# Weird character in C# TimeZoneId

Tags: c#, webforms, sitefinity

I have a Webforms widget in my Sitefinity website and I am using this code to output my Events TimeZones:

```
<span class="time-zone-label"><%# Eval("TimeZoneId")%></span>
```

This works fine for the most part but some of the Time Zones are showing a weird question mark, I believe it's only happening when the event Time Zone is set to "(UTC +00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London", then the output is going to look like this:

[image]

Any idea what this � character is or what it means and how to fix?

Comment: It usually means you're displaying extended unicode characters unsupported by the current font.

Comment: You haven't indicated what your data source is, and you're relying on someone to recognize what that data source has that could be rendered that way. It would be easier to look at the characters yourself (`string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`) and tell us what the unicode code point is, and that might even be the answer to your question right there.

Comment: That's the replacement character. It's used to replace badly encoded text. @Kirk Woll,, It has nothing to do with font support.